# taxonomies or categories w/custom post

Tags: custom-post-types

We are creating a custom post type to showcase a series of archival recordings. They will cover many topics, and be tagged with ideas/phrases from the talks, similar to a regular post. Is it better to create custom taxonomies such as--for example--topics and themes in place of categories and tags, or does it make any difference?

Also, the individual recordings need to be marked w/info such as date recorded, length of recording(s) etc., but this is info that doesn't necessarily need to be searchable. Is it 'better form' (for lack of a way to explain) to create custom taxonomies for these bits of info, or just add them to the description meta box?

thanks for your help..

Don

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the volume of posts you are going to have for recordings and regular posts. if you are talking about a few of each then using the built-in categories and tags will do and you can leverage all of the built-in functions for tags and categories, otherwise there is no harm in using your own taxonomies.

And as for the individual recordings info( date, lenght) if its not needed to be searchable you can use the post's custom fileds for that.

Comment: thank you Bainternet - just the info I needed. much appreciated.